# How to send broadcast message on onCreate method in Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, send, broadcast

I want to send broadcast message to an application and then receive it from current activity. I can send broadcast message but then it couldn't received from broadcast receiver. Here is my code;

```
public class LogIn extends Activity {

    private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                //toast message received !
            }
        };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        //send broadcast message
        Intent i = new Intent(LogIn.class.getName());
        getContext().sendBroadcast(i);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(LogIn.class.getName()));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        try {
            unregisterReceiver(receiver);
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

What is the problem that I missed ? Thank you for your help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the diagram for an [`Activity`'s lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/images/activity_lifecycle.png). The `onCreate()` method runs before `onResume()`, so your sending the broadcast before you've registered the Receiver.

I'm not sure why you'd want to broadcast to the same class, but you can solve your issue by calling the `registerReceiver()` method in `onCreate()` as well, before the `sendBroadcast()` call.

Comment: Hi Mike, thank you for clear answer and do you mean I should create registerreceiver() method in oncreate

Comment: I mean just copy the `registerReceiver()` line you have in `onResume()` to before the `sendBroadcast()` line in `onCreate()`. Get rid of the sticky broadcast, too.

Comment: Yeppp ! I just needed to call registerReceiver() before sending message.. This shows I am not good at  Activity's lifecycle, thank you Mike !

Answer (score 0):

you are registering your receiver with different intent and sending the broadcast with different intent. Thats why you are not receiving your broadcast.

```
public class LogIn extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    //send broadcast message
    Intent i = new Intent("com.abc");
    getContext().sendStickyBroadcast(i);
}
private BroadcastReceiver receiver=new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //toast message received !
        }
    };
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("com.abc"));
}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    try {
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Add Permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY"/>
```

Comment: also you can try with `stickyBroadcastReceiver`